# Canon Pixma MP495 scanner not working on 16.04

Tags: sane, pixma

I cannot seem to get my Canon Pixma MP495 working on Ubuntu 16.04 - just the scanner. It worked fine on 14.04. No problem getting the printer working but no luck with the scanner. I've spent many hours and haven't been able to come up with anything.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem, however if you go to canon website and download the driver and install it for both the printer and the scanner, you will need libtiff4 library (which you can install from the web as a .deb) then you can run 'scangearmp' in terminal, it will allow you to scan.  Note simplescan still doesn't work